# Chrome will not refresh local file when changing backbone template

Tags: google-chrome, backbone.js, underscore.js, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on a backbone application on Google Chrome (v19.0.1084.56) and when I am working on templates, both me (on Mac OSX Lion) and another developer (on Fedora) have to close the tab and reopen the file to see new changes. Forced refresh (cmd+R or f5) do not work.

I am using these flags for chrome to work on the file:

```
open /Applications/Google Chrome.app --args --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security
```

I'm driving myself crazy with this close/open process. Has anyone run into this problem and have you found a way to refresh the file?

**UPDATE:** Another developer in the shop does NOT have the problem described above and is on chrome 18 instead of 19 on Fedora. Its beginning to look like a Chrome bug.

**FURTHER UPDATE:** Also tried using `--disk-cache-size=1 --media-cache-size=1` as flags when opening Chrome and the issue  still persists. Using Incognito Mode doesn't work either. However, if I manually go to `Tools > Clear Browsing History` and check both `Clear Browsing History` and `Empty the Cache`, and hit refresh, the template will load correctly. This narrows it down to a cache problem.

Comment: are your templates just inline on your html page or are you using some type of loader?

Comment: @BenR The templates are being pulled in by a loader. In fact, this loader [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9865476/800917). Unfortunately, the update above negates that this is the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After googling and researching, there is a way to disable cache on a page. By opening the Developer Console, in the bottom right-hand column there is a cog. In that menu there is a checkbox `Disable Cache` that once enabled, fixes the problem.