# TypeScript files get jambed in Chrome Debugger Tools?

Tags: google-chrome, typescript

Real mystery - latest chrome. The .ts file gets stuck in the debugger and won't update. I clear cache, nothing changes. In the debugger tool, the .ts file stays frozen. I tried bouncing the server, closing Chrome. It comes back stuck, I tried deleting the js.map files, no change.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I tried bouncing the server, closing Chrome. It comes back stuck, I tried deleting the js.map files, no change

Open up dev tools. Then right click (or cmd click) the refresh button. Select "empty cache and hard reload" as shown:

[image]